# Why unar extract old rar file?

Tags: centos, command-line, archive, rar

There are 2 rar files in my scenario, their names are `1.rar` and `2.rar`.
My purpose: `1.rar` extract to `folder1` and `2.rar` extract to `folder2`.

First, I extract the `1.rar` file to `folder1` folder with `unar` (`unar -o folder1 x/1.rar`).

Everything is good but if I extract the `2.rar` file to `folder2` (`unar -o folder2 x/2.rar`) then unpacking 1.rar's data into folder2.

Why does it process previous rar file?

OS: Centos 7.

Scenario codes:

```
[root@vm-app home]# unar -o folder1 x/1.rar
x/1.rar: RAR 5
  1/1 - Copy.txt  (0 B)... OK.
  1/1.txt  (0 B)... OK.
  1/  (dir)... OK.
Successfully extracted to "folder1/1".
[root@vm-app home]# unar -o folder2 x/2.rar
x/2.rar: RAR 5
  1/1 - Copy.txt  (0 B)... OK.
  1/1.txt  (0 B)... OK.
  1/  (dir)... OK.
Successfully extracted to "folder2/1".
[root@vm-app home]# ls folder1
1
[root@vm-app home]# ls folder2
1
[root@vm-app home]# rm -rf folder1 && rm -rf folder2
[root@vm-app home]# unar -o folder2 x/2.rar
x/2.rar: RAR 5
  1/1 - Copy.txt  (0 B)... OK.
  1/1.txt  (0 B)... OK.
  1/  (dir)... OK.
Successfully extracted to "folder2/1".
[root@vm-app home]# rm -rf folder2
[root@vm-app home]# rm x/1.rar
rm: remove regular file ‘x/1.rar’? y
[root@vm-app home]# unar -o folder2 x/2.rar
x/2.rar: RAR 5
  2/2 - Copy.txt  (0 B)... OK.
  2/2.txt  (0 B)... OK.
  2/  (dir)... OK.
Successfully extracted to "folder2/2".
[root@vm-app home]# ls folder2
2
[root@vm-app home]#
```

Comment: Are you sure that contents of `2.rar` differs from what has been unpacked into `folder2`? Is it any different when you skip first step (unpacking `1.rar`)?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. `2.rar` has different content from `1.rar`.  I updated the question for codes.

Comment: @Theophrastus Thanks, I try but didn't work. Also -o means 'output-directory'.

Comment: i really don't think you want to use "unar" on rar archives.  here's the description of "unar" from a package manager:  "An utility to extract, test and view the contents of archives created with the ARJ archiver"  that is, (i blather once more): you want "unrar" for rar achives (not "unar")  good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your help and explanation. I used `unrar` and its worked. But still I don't understand why `unar` isn't working..